# Swift TableView not same height on Iphone 4s and Iphone 5s

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a TableView on my app but the problem is that on a Iphone 4s the height is perfect but on a Iphone 5s the height is not getting higher here is some pictures:

[image: Iphone 4s]

[image: Iphone 5s]

I wan't my TableView to end on the top of the ToolBar on both devices. How can i do that?

Comment: Can you change the background of the tableView to see if it's the cells or the actual Tableview which doesn't fit the screen. Coz maybe it's simply that the TableaView fill the entire screen but you don't have enough cells. Make sense ?

Comment: Else you have to make sure that the margin constrains of top and bottom are 0 and not on height

Comment: Thanks i only had to add the margin contrains you can post a answer i will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

So I post the answer for everyone, 2 possible answers :

- The real answer for the actual issue : All the constrains aren't set : xcode 6 has got [4 constrains buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y37ZA.png) in the bottom right of the IB view.! Click on the second left button and add constrains to the top and bottom to 0 then click on the third and click Update Contrains if there is an ambiguity (orange markup on the view).
- A clue if it doesn't work : The second is that you don't have enough cells to complete the view but your tableview still be in full height.